# How to stash a merge with conflicts without losing the conflicts?

Tags: git

I have a big merge with many conflicts, that will take time for me to resolve. During that time, I have to also work on other branches so I need to switch to other branches while still having merge conflicts going. I tried to stash the merge, but that loses the conflicts. After I return to the branch and apply the stash, git no longer sees the conflicts (even there are still the HEAD <<<<<<< markers there). Is there a way to reactivate the merge conflicts in git so that git will understand there are unresolved conflicts?

How to stash the merge so that it will remember the conflicts after I apply the stash? Or then any other way to work around this issue? I feel like once I'm in the state of resolving merge conflicts, I'm stuck there and have to finish it before working on another branch. I can always abort the merge, but then I lose progress.

I heard git worktree might solve this problem? It's not familiar to me.

Comment: git worktree can solve the problem by creating a new worktree for working on other branches while you are resolving the conflicts in the original worktree.

Comment: worktree is the way to go. `git help worktree`

Comment: Do you have reinstall dependencies with worktree? Does it save files that are not tracked by version control? If not, I would have to copy some files to the new folder etc..